# JDBI can't bind PGInterval to PostgreSQL INTERVAL

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, jdbi, postgresql-13, jdbi3-core

When attempting to update or insert a table containing an INTERVAL in PostgreSQL using JDBI, I'm getting the following error:
`org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.UnableToCreateStatementException: No argument factory registered for '1 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.0 secs' of qualified type org.postgresql.util.PGInterval [...]`

Minimal reproducible example:

- In Database:

```sql
CREATE TABLE testing (i INTERVAL);
```

- In Kotlin (Likely yields the same result in plain Java):

```kotlin
Jdbi.create(PGSimpleDataSource().apply {
        setURL([connection string goes here])
    }).withHandle<Int, SQLException> { handle: Handle ->
        handle.createUpdate("INSERT INTO testing(i) VALUES (:interval)")
                .bind("interval", PGInterval(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0))
                .execute()
    }
```

I've tried inserting it as a string since queries accept 'P1Y', but that gives me `ERROR: column "i" is of type interval but expression is of type character varying`, which would make sense if the first method worked.

It seems like it would only make sense for PGIntervals to be the expected type to work, since when obtaining intervals from a result set, a PGInterval is returned.

Although I somehow doubt it'll matter, I'm using:

- PostgreSQL 13.2 (Debian 13.2-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
- org.jdbi:jdbi3-core:3.18.1 + org.jdbi:jdbi3-kotlin:3.18.1 + org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should use [PostgreSQL JDBI Plugin](http://jdbi.org/#_postgresql) to work with PostgreSQL-specific types.